# How to prevent user logout by WebSecurity.ChangePassword()

Tags: asp.net

I was trying to let the users change their password in settings. In the ajax page, I was using

```
WebSecurity.Logout();
```

So I thought logging out is because of this code. But then I noticed that the user logs out, even if this line isn't present after Password change success. So I tried to Google it. And on many places I found that this code removes the Cache and Cookies, so the user is logged out.

**My Question:** Is there any way to prevent User logout? Or can I save the Cookie or cache so that the user is still logged in after password change success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `WebSecurity.ChangePassword`, this will renew the current cookie with all new crendentials and then send it back into the response.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Manage(ChangePassward model)
{
    bool changePasswordSucceeded = false;

    try
    {
        changePasswordSucceeded = WebSecurity.ChangePassword(User.Identity.Name, model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        changePasswordSucceeded = false;
    }

    if (changePasswordSucceeded)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Some Page here", new { Message = "Success" });
    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The current password is incorrect or the new password is invalid.");
    }
}
```

Comment: That's true! But that will also log the user out. Which I donot want to. I want him to stay active even if his Password has been changed!

Comment: And also, this one is `MVC` I want `ASP.NET Web Pages/Razor`. However, thanks for your time and help! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, so apologies for bringing it back to life, but for anyone else who faces this issue:

You already have their username and password in this method. Log them back in.